# How to add characters to a textbox when a div is clicked using jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm building my own jquery keyboard and I need to enter x character to x field when a div is clicked or touched.

This is some of my keyboard HTML structure:

```
<input id="name" name="name" type="text" />

<div class="key-row" style="width: 1092px;">
    <div id="k-q" class="key">Q</div>
    <div id="k-w" class="key">W</div>
    <div id="k-e" class="key">E</div>
    <div id="k-r" class="key">R</div>
    <div id="k-t" class="key">T</div>
    <div id="k-y" class="key">Y</div>
    <div id="k-u" class="key">U</div>
    <div id="k-i" class="key">I</div>
    <div id="k-o" class="key">O</div>
    <div id="k-p" class="key">P</div>
</div>
```

This is the jquery that I'm working on:

```
$( "#k-q" ).click(function() {
    //alert( "Q pressed" );
    // $('#name').append('Q');
    // $("input[type='text']").append('some new text')
    // $('#name').add( "aaaaa" );
    //$('#name').text('Q');
    $('#name').val('Q');
});
```

As you can see I have already tried diferent ways to do the input. The only one that did the work was the one with the var() method, but I can't use it becuase it only replaces the text already entered. I need this in a way that if I press "Q" 3 times, the letter "Q" appears 3 times in the textbox.

How can I do this with jquery or javascript?

Comment: Try this : http://jsfiddle.net/d57zcfmy/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This snippet adds the letters into the text box. If you want to just put the clicked letter, remove the variable `currentName`

```js
$("div.key").click(function(e){
  var currentName = $("#name").val();
  $("#name").val(currentName + $(this).text());
});
```

```css
.key{
border: 1px solid #333;
padding: 2px;
width: 16px;
margin: 1px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="name" name="name" type="text" />

<div class="key-row" style="width: 1092px;">
    <div id="k-q" class="key">Q</div>
    <div id="k-w" class="key">W</div>
    <div id="k-e" class="key">E</div>
    <div id="k-r" class="key">R</div>
    <div id="k-t" class="key">T</div>
    <div id="k-y" class="key">Y</div>
    <div id="k-u" class="key">U</div>
    <div id="k-i" class="key">I</div>
    <div id="k-o" class="key">O</div>
    <div id="k-p" class="key">P</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow! Excellent! Thanks!

Comment: @OscarOtero. I'm happy I could help. If you found what you were looking for, please select the answer as the solution. So, no more developer spends time on it

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to write every click of the div, instead, you can use the class selector. And you can grab the input value every time to append to it.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".key").click(function() {
    $('#name').val($('#name').val() + this.innerText);
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can grab the inputs current value and then append your new letter to it:

`$("#name").val($("#name").val() + "Q");`

Answer (score 0):

Check this out - it'll be much simpler for you.

```js
/*
 * By obtaining a reference at the beginning,
 * we prevent unnecessary calls
 */
var $input = $('#name');


/*
 * We can get all of the keys by using '.key'
 */
$('.key').click(e => {
  /**
   * We are clicking on the div, so the event's target
   * is the div. This element is not wrapped by jQuery,
   * so we use the DOM textContent property.
   */
  var characterToAppend = e.target.textContent;
  /**
   * The .val() function without any parameters will
   * return the current contents of an input element.
   * We add the new character to it to prevent the
   * box from clearing out like you mentioned.
   */
  var newTextContent = $input.val() + characterToAppend;
  $input.val(newTextContent);
});
```

```css
.key-row {
  background-color: rgb(50, 50, 75);
  bottom: 0;
  display: flex;
  padding: 50px;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100vw;
}

.key {
  background-color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  padding: 16px;
  transition: box-shadow 500ms;
}

.key:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px black;
  z-index: 2; /* Show the shadow above the other boxes */
}
```

```html
<input id="name" name="name" type="text" />

<div class="key-row">
  <div id="k-q" class="key">Q</div>
  <div id="k-w" class="key">W</div>
  <div id="k-e" class="key">E</div>
  <div id="k-r" class="key">R</div>
  <div id="k-t" class="key">T</div>
  <div id="k-y" class="key">Y</div>
  <div id="k-u" class="key">U</div>
  <div id="k-i" class="key">I</div>
  <div id="k-o" class="key">O</div>
  <div id="k-p" class="key">P</div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Much easier to read and understand than what you were doing earlier. Also, sorry, but I couldn't resist styling the keyboard at least a little.